# Strange occurrence of glue drying

Tags: everyday-life, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, chemical-compounds, adhesion

[image]

What happened here? I by accident spilled super glue and formed these amazing ridge patterns. Any ideas what caused this to happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related: [Atlas of thin film patterns](http://john.maloney.org/Patterns/patterns.htm) (including those arising from drying and surface curing).

Answer (score 2):

Superglue hardens from the surface because [curing is driven by humidity from the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate#Polymerization).

From what we are seeing I assume that during curing the layer expands (this is the case for drying oils like linseed oil and oil based paints). The layer is attached at the sides and its surface area increases, so the only thing that can happen is that it forms crinkles. (And the structure is more or less regular because bending the surface layer costs energy, so all the bends need to have roughly the same radius, modulo effects near the points where the surface layer adheres to the surroundings).

(Note, that I could not a find a source, on whether superglue expands on curing – in so far my answer is provisional.)

Answer (score 2):

Adhesives typically shrink when hardening. They obviously also get hard when hardening. Depending on the particulars of the adhesive, sometimes it wants to keep shrinking well after its viscosity has risen to the level of effectively being a solid. As a result, stress will build up. Under favorable conditions, these ridges form due to buckling under the stress (to relieve it).

BTW when I ran into this phenomenon at work and all the assembled parts broke, I interpreted the conditions as unfavorable ;)

As an experiment, Try to coat some of this adhesive on a piece of paper (while taking precautions to not glue yourself to… well, anything).
You will see that the paper rolls up, with the glue side inwards. Cool.